# Messagebox based on If Statement

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

solved!

```
    global entry
    label.config(text = entry.get())
    if entry == "" or " ":
```

needed to be:

```
    global entry
    entry_write1 = entry.get()
    entry_write = entry_write1.strip()
    label.config(text = entry_write)
    if entry_write == "" or entry_write == " ":
```

This way I can strip the whitespace from entry.get() so multiple spaces will bring the error box up too!

Thank you for the help!

---

Orginal Posting:

Using python here, and this was one of my assignments(and like, the first one I was able to do 95% by myself lmao).

I'm just having trouble getting my messagebox to stop popping up after every click of the button. I was using an if statement to try and get it to only pop up when there's no text. I know I'm missing something here!

I tried creating a little 'else:' with the label.config, but it wouldn't change the label and the messagebox would still pop up. Messing around with it further didn't seem to help either.

Here's my code:

```
#import everything and keeping an eye on messagebox
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

#make window
window = tk.Tk()

#create exit button that destroys window upon button press
ExitButton = tk.Button(text = "Exit", command = window.destroy, width = 2, height = 1, bg = "red2", fg = "ghost white")
ExitButton.pack()


#creating entry field and label, adding them to window
entry = tk.Entry()
label = tk.Label(text = "Enter Text Here: ")
label.pack()
entry.pack()

#function for changing label text in ExecuteButton
def changeLabelText():
    global entry
    label.config(text = entry.get())
    if entry == "" or " ":
        msg = messagebox.showerror("ERROR", "No Text To Display")

#creating execute button for command = ChangeLabelText and adding to window
ExecuteButton = tk.Button(text = "Execute", command = changeLabelText, width = 5, height = 1, bg = "forest green", fg = "gold",)
ExecuteButton.pack()


#create event loop
window.mainloop()
```

If anyone could help me refine the messagebox issue, that would be lovely.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Currently your code is:

```
label.config(text = entry.get())
if entry == "" or " ":
```

Why are you checking on `entry` if you are putting your information in the `text` variable?
Hence I would opt for:

```
label.config(text = entry.get())
if (text == "") or (text == " "):
```

As you see, checking if a variable equals one of the values is not done using:

```
var == value1 OR value2
```

But:

```
var == value1 OR var == value2
```

Comment: Can also be checked as `var in [value1, value2]`.

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer. Unfortunately when implementing the advice it appears that the messagebox will not open at all and that the 'text' was not defined(which I believe I fixed by doing 'entry_write = label.config(text = entry.get()), and referring to entry_write for the if statement) Not sure why that is so I'll be messing around with it some more for a little bit. I did try a few diffferent ways, like @theherk version as well but I think I'm missing something else there.

Comment: Oops! Solved, had a big brain moment and referred to entry.get() for the if statement instead of just text/entry/entry_write. Solved my issue, haha. Thank you both!